# MVC application page loading without style later a second style applies

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Created a MVC application. Here i have only one view page. When page loads, controls css not applying and after 2-3 seconds css are getting applied.
Its looks odd. Tried but didnt get any clue to find the issue.

Used Bootstrap table class

```
@section Styles
{
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/DayOfWeek.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/Index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/MonthYear.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/MutualExclusiveParam.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/YearMonthDay.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/HourMinute.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Index/DayOfWeek.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.db').attr('data-live-search', true);
</script>
}
<div class="col-md-1">
        @Html.Label(@parameter.parameterLabel)
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownList(parameter.parameterLabel.Trim() + '_' + parameter.parameterId, Model.salesAreaItems)
        </div>
```

[image]
Please let me know, any idea on this.

Comment: Are you doing refresh in order for styles to appear? Or Is it automatically appearing after a few seconds?

Comment: No, Automatically its appearing after a few seconds.

Comment: Does the browser's network monitor give you any clues?

Comment: no exceptions are coming

Comment: You're looking for timing issues with the network monitor. It will show the activity over the wire and see if it lines up with what you are observing with the rendered output.

Comment: Source order you styles/scripts by their importance to the page render. For example, since Bootstrap is generally responsible for the base style (grid, fonts, colors, etc.), it should pretty much always be the first thing loaded. Contrarily, jQuery UI's CSS is not important until jQuery UI JS has loaded, and it's also very heavy, so that could be pretty much the last style loaded, as all the style will likely load before all the JS.

Comment: You also need to load general to specific. For example, it seems `Common.css` is basically your app's main style. If you load it before Bootstrap, then you have no ability to override any of the general styles Bootstrap adds with more specific style relevant to your app.

Comment: Hi Jasen, Chris. 
I have followed your suggestion but no luck .  I have added my network tab details too. Please share your comments on this. Thanks in advance.